How do I host a wesbite through github or add a link to my respiratory page?
I currently have a Python-based website with CSS and HTML incorporated to make the interface. The website is tied to a research project so I'm trying to upload it on figshare. Is there a way to upload my website onto figshare? Possibly through GitHub?
I tried to upload my website through github.io but found out I have to pay for the pro version. I was thinking about using something like render to host the website (for accessibility), linking it to GitHub, and then from there, uploading my GitHub to Figshare. Although, I'm not too sure how. The goal is to make the website accessible for other people through Figshare without having to download all the files and run it on an application like vscode.

I'm not familiar with Figshare, but presumably they provide information about what services they provide and how to use them.  As for hosting a website on GitHub, if that website isn't just a static page and instead has server-side code then GitHub is unlikely to support hosting it.  You'd need to find and use a web host that supports whatever server-side technologies you're using.

I'll look into that. Thank you! I'm currently trying to use render to deploy the Flask application.
